How to use dependency_injector with pytest?
I am trying to test my code using pytest and I am having a problem to test some functions that use the database. I decided to use Dependency Injection. I have used in TypeScript before using tysyring, so I have some idea what I have to do.
In python I decided to use the lib dependency_injector, however I am having a hard time to understand how I can replace my database connection with a mock.
To make things simple I made a simple code to try to learn dependency_injectcion:
class DB:
    def fetch_data(self):
        return "data from db"

class DBMOck:
    def fetch_data_mock(self):
        return "data from db mock"

class Contract:

    def process(self):
        db = DB()
        return db.fetch_data()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    contract = Contract()

    print(contract.process())

import pytest

def test_contract_process():

    contract = Contract()

    assert contract.process() == "data from repository mock"

The class DB is responsible to connect to my database and fetch data.
The class Contract is a class that is used to do a service like retrieve a contract from db to the user.
Now I need to test my code, but only contract. However I wanna to mock the database, instead retrieve data from DB the code needs to retrieve from DBMock.
Is there a way to use dependecy injection to inject the DBMock into a interface to the class Contract access the mock class instead of the DB in the tests?
I can't change the class contract signature.
So I couldn't do something like that:
class Contract:

    def process(self, myDB):
        return myDB.fetch_data()

